# How to refactor repeating of similar getters and setters in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, dry

In my rails model I have something like

def price
      Money.new(price_cents, currency)
    end

```
def price=(val)
  price_cents = val.to_money.cents
end

def value
  Money.new(value_cents, currency)
end

def value=(val)
  value_cents = val.to_money.cents
end

def budget
  Money.new(budget_cents, currency)
end

def budget=(val)
  budget_cents = val.to_money.cents
end

def used
  Money.new(used_cents, currency)
end

def used=(val)
  used_cents = val.to_money.cents
end
```

This is obviously not very DRY. How could I refactor this?

Comment: Have you seen composed_of ( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html )

Comment: I used composed_of before, but i don't want to change the currency through price, value, etc. This makes it hard to use composed_of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that [thing]_cents stuff refers to attributes of an ActiveRecord model. If so, I think you could do something along these lines (apologies for not testing this - hopefully it's at least directionally helpful):

```
[:price, :value, :budget, :used].each do |prefix|

  self.class.send(:define_method, "#{prefix}=") do |val|
    write_attribute("#{prefix}_cents".to_sym, val.to_money.cents)
  end

  self.class.send(:define_method, "#{prefix}") do
    Money.new(read_attribute("#{prefix}_cents".to_sym), currency)
  end

end
```

Comment: This worked great! I put it in a separate module. Also added the line `instance_eval "#{prefix}_cents_will_change!"` to the setter.